# Can a carrera valor mountain bike be converted to disk brakes?

Tags: mountain-bike

My Carrera valour mountain bike currently has v-brakes but the are not very good and to be honest they look a bit tacky compared to disc brakes, is it possible to convert it to disk brakes, because I'm not sure whether my bike has a suitable frame...

Comment: Cheapest, easiest and most reliable way to convert almost any bike is sell it and buy one with discs.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming [this](http://www.halfords.com/cycling/bikes/mountain-bikes/carrera-valour-mens-mountain-bike-2015) is your bike, the answer would be no.  You could technically add disk brakes on the front, but it would require changing the forks to ones that had attachment points for disk brakes. You would also have to change the wheels/hubs to ones that are compatible for mounting the disk.  There is no good method of adding disk brakes to the rear as this frame is aluminum and adding disk brake mounting points after the fact isn't a good idea.

Why do you feel that you need disk brakes? V-Brakes can perform quite well if they are adjusted right and are good quality. A good set of v-brakes will work better than a cheap set of disk brakes.

Comment: He mentioned he wants disc breaks due to the look not performance.

Comment: You can always put on discs without calipers and leave the V brakes. Yourbikehatesyou will probably want a photo.

Comment: @ojs you would still need disk hubs. Although you could just glue them on or zip-tie them to the spokes since they won't be functional anyway.